# Node.js on ubuntu16.04 - Failing to install and run nodemon

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, node-modules, nodemon

I'm failing to install and run nodemon. I'm running node.js on ubuntu 16.04.. My api is working. The libs installed are:

```
sven@sven-MS-7264:~/Projects/APIDemo$ npm -g ls --depth=0
/usr/lib
├── npm@5.6.0
└── pm2@2.9.3

npm ERR! invalid: minizlib@1.0.3 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minizlib

sven@sven-MS-7264:~/Projects/APIDemo$ npm ls --depth=0
apidemo@1.0.0 /home/sven/Projects/APIDemo
├── body-parser@1.18.2
├── cookie-parser@1.4.3
├── debug@3.1.0
├── ejs@2.5.7
├── express@4.16.2
├── morgan@1.9.0
├── mysql@2.15.0
└── serve-favicon@2.4.5
```

But when trying to install nodemon globally, I'm getting this:

```
sven@sven-MS-7264:~/Projects/APIDemo$ npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

The folder permission looks like this:

```
sven@sven-MS-7264:~/Projects$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 sven sven 4096 Feb 20 09:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 52 sven sven 4096 Feb 20 13:59 ..
drwx------  7 sven sven 4096 Feb 20 16:27 APIDemo
```

How can I install and run nodemon?

Comment: `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Comment: `chown -R sven:sven /usr/lib/node_modules`.

Comment: Thanks ... I installed it globally with sudo and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install a global module if you are not as an admin. Try to run the command with `sudo` if you can

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

You can also install nodemon in your local folder by removing the `-g` option.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB9Fq9I5ocs ... is it better globally oder local?

Comment: It depends on the usage of nodemon. If you are using nodemon as a daemon process, install it as global. If multiple users may use nodemon on the server, install it as global. If you may need nodemon from multiple locations on the server, install it globally. Otherwise, install locally.

Comment: Thanks ... I installed it globally with sudo and it works.